# UIImagePickerController black screen issue

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

An application of mine makes use of a `UIImagePickerController` instance as follows:

1. Provide a UI with a split-view between the camera and saved-photos view.
2. The saved-photos view consists of a collection view
3. The camera view consists of a container-view that adds a `UIImagePickerController` as a child view controller with source type `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera`

The issue, similar to what many others seem to have faced, is that when I navigate to other view controllers and return to the starting view-controller, the camera view turns black. The camera controls still function and pictures are able to be taken, but the view remains completely black.

I have tried the following solutions:

1. Remove the previous child-view-controller instance, and create and add a new one every time in `viewDidAppear`. This works, but seems totally unnecessary.
2. Add the the `imagePickerController`'s view as a subview of the container-view, but without calling `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`. This obviously looks bad because it breaks the parent-child paradigm of view-controllers in UIKit.

I figure the second solution works because, since the `imagePickerController` is not a child-view-controller, it doesn't get informed of events like `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` through its parent (since it has no parent).

Is there any other way I could get around the problem? 
And do any of you know precisely why this issue exists?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use this function 'startVideoCapture()' of UIImagePickerViewController in viewWillAppear().

Comment: But I don't want to start video capture? Moreover, how would it fix the issue of the camera view not being visible?

Comment: You can do like this let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        vc.startVideoCapture()

Comment: Again, I don't want to startVideoCapture. I'm just interested in getting rid of the unexplained black space.